# VBA If Statement Formula in a Loop and Range Function to Get Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

I am trying to assign If formula to certain cell every 16th row. Formula needs to compare values of cells in J, K and L columns and gives Pass or Fail Result.

I am having issues making this If formula work in a loop. Please Help! My Code is below.

First I am getting compile error saying " Expected end of statement"

Second, is there any other way to make these work? I need same formula applied to Cell M5 to M789 at every 16th cell.

```
For a = 5 To 789 Step 16

   Range("M" & a).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Range("J" & a)>= Range("K" & a),IF(Range("J" & a))<= Range("L" & a),""PASS"", ""FAIL""),""FAIL"")"
```

Comment: 1) You need `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1`. 2) Don't use `Range` within a formula - that's mixing VBA into regular worksheet formulas. You can't use `Range(J5)` in a worksheet - just `J5`.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of Range, what else can I use to get values of J5 to J789, K5 to K789 and L5 to L789 cells within a loop?

Comment: Just `"J"`, `"K"`, and `"L"` - drop the `Range` calls from the formula part.

Comment: Range("M" & a).Formula = "=IF(("J" & a)>=("K" & a),IF(("J" & a)<= ("L" & a),""PASS"", ""FAIL""),""FAIL"")" OK i removed the Range part and still gives me compile error for "expected end of statement" with "J" highlighted.

Comment: ben Thanks for your help. I made some changes and it finally works.              Range("M" & a).Formula = "=IF(J" & a & " >= K" & a & ",IF(J" & a & " <= L" & a & ",""PASS"", ""FAIL""),""FAIL"")"

Comment: hi. J K and L must have double quotes ""J"" ""K"" and ""L""

Comment: One could also ask the question if you really need these cells to be filled with a formula. What purpose does it have. Are `J`, `K` and `L` column values going to change? Otherwise you are doing unnecessary calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1` - you are not using R1C1 references.
2. Remove the `Range` calls from the formula part. That's mixing VBA with regular worksheet formula syntax.
3. You can simplify the formula using AND. And in this case you don't need to concatenate `a` in at all. Excel is smart enough to update relative references.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myFormula As String
    myFormula = "=IF(AND(J5>=K5,J5<=L5),""PASS"",""FAIL"")"

    Dim a As Long
    For a = 5 To 789 Step 16
        Range("M" & a).Formula = myFormula
    Next
End Sub
```